# Python SMTP Client - error in sendmail method

Tags: python, smtp, smtpclient, smtplib

*TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'*

```
from smtplib import SMTP

def signin():
    email='example@example.com'
    password='password'
    conn.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    conn.starttls()
    conn.login(adresa,lozinka)

def write_send_message():
    message=dict()

    message['From:']='example@example.com'
    message['To:']='example2@example.com'
    message['Subject:']='Test message'
    message['Message:']=r'''Test message from Python interpeter'''
    
    print('Sending the message...:')
    for key in message:
        print(unos,poruka[unos])
    SMTP.sendmail(message['From:'],message['To:'],message['Message:'])
    

host='smtpserver.smtp.com'
port=587
conn=SMTP(host,port)


signin()


write_send_message ()
```

I'm not sure where did I make the mistake. Third argument (message['Message']) is my variable containing the text of the message (the value of key 'Message' of the same named dictionary). What do you suggest me to change ?
There's a simallar question (about 6 years old now, was programmed with Tkinter) with the same error. That didn't help here.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html \n
In Python's documentation it says that 'msg' should be a string which is true in my case. I've tried with `sendmail` but since I've established a connection with the server successfully with `ehlo` method, it actually wasn't needed.

Comment: Can you post the error with a full trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Flash\Desktop\SMTP.py", line 32, in <module>
    write_send_message()
  File "C:\Users\Flash\Desktop\SMTP.py", line 21, in write_send_message
    SMTP.sendmail(message['From:'],message['To:'],message['Message:'])
TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'  


I guess that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `conn.sendmail` rather than `SMPT.sendmail`.